# Why I am getting libhdf5_hl not loaded error during executing the HDF5 example code?

Tags: c, hdf5

I am trying to executing the c program to execute the HDF5 basic code. That is here below.

```
/*
 *  This example illustrates how to create a dataset that is a 4 x 6
 *  array.  It is used in the HDF5 Tutorial.
 */

#include "hdf5.h"
#define FILE "dset.h5"

int main() {

   hid_t       file_id, dataset_id, dataspace_id;  /* identifiers */
   hsize_t     dims[2];
   herr_t      status;

   /* Create a new file using default properties. */
   file_id = H5Fcreate(FILE, H5F_ACC_TRUNC, H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT);

   /* Create the data space for the dataset. */
   dims[0] = 4;
   dims[1] = 6;
   dataspace_id = H5Screate_simple(2, dims, NULL);

   /* Create the dataset. */
   dataset_id = H5Dcreate2(file_id, "/dset", H5T_STD_I32BE, dataspace_id,
                          H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT);

   /* End access to the dataset and release resources used by it. */
   status = H5Dclose(dataset_id);

   /* Terminate access to the data space. */
   status = H5Sclose(dataspace_id);

   /* Close the file. */
   status = H5Fclose(file_id);
}
```

I am not getting any compile time error, but run time error saying it is not able load some lib. The error is pasted below -

```
19:36:27 macOS_ ⚡   h5cc -show myprog.c
clang -arch x86_64 myprog.c -L/Users/Ajay/anaconda/lib -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -arch x86_64 -lpthread -lz -ldl -lm
19:36:33 macOS_ ⚡  ./a.out
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libhdf5_hl.10.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/Ajay/opensource/HDF5-Examples/./a.out
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
19:36:35 macOS_ ⚡
```

more information on configuration -

```
09:11:59 macOS_ ⚡  h5cc -showconfig
        SUMMARY OF THE HDF5 CONFIGURATION
        =================================

General Information:
-------------------
           HDF5 Version: 1.8.17
          Configured on: Tue Aug  2 08:44:51 BST 2016
          Configured by: ray@rays-Mac.local
         Configure mode: production
            Host system: i386-apple-darwin11.4.2
          Uname information: Darwin rays-Mac.local 11.4.2 Darwin Kernel Version 11.4.2: Thu Aug 23 16:25:48 PDT 2012; root:xnu-1699.32.7~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
               Byte sex: little-endian
              Libraries: shared
         Installation point: /Users/Ajay/anaconda

Compiling Options:
------------------
               Compilation Mode: production
                     C Compiler: /usr/bin/clang ( Apple LLVM version 4.2 )
                         CFLAGS:  -arch x86_64
                      H5_CFLAGS:  -O3
                      AM_CFLAGS: 
                       CPPFLAGS: 
                    H5_CPPFLAGS:   -DNDEBUG -UH5_DEBUG_API
                    AM_CPPFLAGS: 
               Shared C Library: yes
               Static C Library: no
  Statically Linked Executables: no
                        LDFLAGS:  -arch x86_64
                     H5_LDFLAGS: 
                     AM_LDFLAGS: 
        Extra libraries: -lpthread -lz -ldl -lm 
               Archiver: ar
             Ranlib: ranlib
          Debugged Packages: 
            API Tracing: no

Languages:
----------
                        Fortran: no

                            C++: yes
                   C++ Compiler: /usr/bin/clang++ ( Apple LLVM version 4.2 )
                      C++ Flags:  -arch x86_64
                   H5 C++ Flags:  -O3
                   AM C++ Flags: 
             Shared C++ Library: yes
             Static C++ Library: no

Features:
---------
                  Parallel HDF5: no
             High Level library: yes
                   Threadsafety: yes
            Default API Mapping: v18
 With Deprecated Public Symbols: yes
         I/O filters (external): deflate(zlib)
                            MPE: no
                     Direct VFD: no
                        dmalloc: no
Clear file buffers before write: yes
           Using memory checker: no
         Function Stack Tracing: no
      Strict File Format Checks: no
   Optimization Instrumentation: no
```

*lib locations*

```
09:11:56 macOS_ ⚡  ls /Users/Ajay/anaconda/lib | grep hdf5
-rwxr-xr-x    2 Ajay  staff     17232 Aug  2  2016 libhdf5_hl_cpp.11.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x    2 Ajay  staff    123256 Aug  2  2016 libhdf5_hl.10.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x    2 Ajay  staff    445776 Aug  2  2016 libhdf5_cpp.12.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x    2 Ajay  staff   2622428 Aug  2  2016 libhdf5.10.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x    1 Ajay  staff        20 Mar 25 09:11 libhdf5_cpp.dylib -> libhdf5_cpp.12.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x    1 Ajay  staff        16 Mar 25 09:11 libhdf5.dylib -> libhdf5.10.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x    1 Ajay  staff      1087 Mar 25 09:11 libhdf5_hl_cpp.la
lrwxr-xr-x    1 Ajay  staff        23 Mar 25 09:11 libhdf5_hl_cpp.dylib -> libhdf5_hl_cpp.11.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x    1 Ajay  staff       988 Mar 25 09:11 libhdf5_hl.la
lrwxr-xr-x    1 Ajay  staff        19 Mar 25 09:11 libhdf5_hl.dylib -> libhdf5_hl.10.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x    1 Ajay  staff       993 Mar 25 09:11 libhdf5_cpp.la
-rw-r--r--    1 Ajay  staff      2243 Mar 25 09:11 libhdf5.settings
-rwxr-xr-x    1 Ajay  staff       937 Mar 25 09:11 libhdf5.la
```

> > Based on the comment I can now run using 
> >     `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/Ajay/anaconda/lib ./a.out`
> >     How to make it permanent ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not on a Mac and don't use Anaconda. I'll try to guess-diagnose your problem anyway :-)

1. The program builds but will not execute. There is a mismatch between the libraries that are requested by the executable (`libhdf5_hl.10.dylib`) and the ones that are in your system.
2. You are using Anaconda installed hdf5. You must check what is the compiler used by Anaconda to build hdf5 and use the same.

The easiest way out is if all that is missing is the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` path to `/Users/Ajay/anaconda/lib`. Try

```
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/Ajay/anaconda/lib ./a.out
```

For further info, please provide the output of

```
ls /Users/Ajay/anaconda/lib | grep hdf5
h5cc -showconfig
```

Comment: you are a genius, trust me saved a lot of time . I cracked my head like anything .... Super

Comment: For your further question, this issue has been seen by other users but should not *in principle* occur. One possibility is to export the variable in the .bashrc file with `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/Ajay/anaconda/lib` but this can lead to other type of errors with anaconda, see https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/1169 Another possibility is to re-build hdf5 with an updated recipe :-/